# Dynamically added row didn't show in GridView.Rows.Count

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am working on a gridview and adding some rows dynamically to the gridview using C#. But in code behind when I do `grd.Rows.Count` it only shows the count of normal rows.

Following is my code for add the row:

```
GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(e.Row.RowIndex + descriptionRowIndex, e.Row.RowIndex + descriptionRowIndex, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Insert);

row_index = grdFileUpload1.Rows.Count + descriptionRowIndex;

// Adding Group Expand Collapse Cell 
TableCell cell = new TableCell();

// Adding Header Cell
cell = new TableCell();
cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
cell.Text = "File Description";
cell.Font.Bold = true;
cell.ColumnSpan = 1;
cell.CssClass = "";
row.Cells.Add(cell);

// Adding Description Column
cell = new TableCell();
Label lblfile_desc = new Label();
cell.Controls.Add(lblfile_desc);//file_description.Value;
cell.Text = Session["file_description"].ToString();
cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
cell.ColumnSpan = 3;
cell.CssClass = "";
row.Cells.Add(cell);

row.ID = "collapsedRow" + row_index;
row.Attributes.Add("Style", "Display:none");

grdFileUpload1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(row_index, row);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this can help.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("COLUMN1", typeof(string));

DataRow NewRow = dt.NewRow();
NewRow[0] = "TEXT";
dt.Rows.Add(NewRow); 
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridViewl.DataBind();
```